# GitLab CI/CD minutes quota

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

My gitlab projects trigger jenkins via webhook. Jenkins has a gitlab plugin which updates job status (penging, success or failed). Today I encountered a problem with gitlab jobs quota... Why is that? GitLab doc says they count minutes used by gitlab shared runner, but I am using external job. Any advises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GitLab plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/) will trigger the use of a GitLab runner (possibly a [shared runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/runners_scope.html#shared-runners), which does impact [CICD minutes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/cicd_minutes.html)), if a job is triggered from GitLab.

Even when sending the build status back to GitLab, where it will be visible in the commit and/or merge request UI, it could involve a shared runner.

Check if that is the case by viewing your [CI/CD minutes used by a personal namespace](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/cicd_minutes.html#view-cicd-minutes-used-by-a-personal-namespace).

---

Note that See [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#view-shared-runner-usage-per-project-in-a-group) (June 2022) adds:

> ### View shared runner usage per project in a group
>
> Using shared SaaS runners for public projects have the same CI/CD minutes limits as the corresponding tier the project is on. Users managing groups could see the total runner usage for the entire group, but could not see the usage for individual projects in one place. This made it hard to identify which projects within a group were using the most CI/CD minutes.
>
> Now you can see the SaaS runner usage for the group by project, the same as you can in a personal namespace. It is now easier to find the projects that are using the most CI/CD minutes and, if necessary, make their pipelines more efficient.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_1/verify-group-shared-saas-runner-usage.png -- View shared runner usage per project in a group]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/cicd_minutes.html#view-cicd-minutes-used-by-a-group) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/355666).

---

Plus, [GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#enforce-per-plan-webhook-rate-limits) (July 2022) adds:

> ### Enforce per-plan webhook rate limits
>
> Webhook rate limits will now be enforced for GitLab.com users to protect the performance and availability of the GitLab application. In return, the limit protects performance for all tenants.
>
> Limits are applied per plan and per namespace and are based on the number of seats in your subscription, starting at 500 and up to 13,000 calls per minute per top-level namespace.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#rate-limits) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/365605).

---

What can also help to reduce minutes is a faster SaaS runner, with [GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#medium-saas-runners-on-linux-available-to-all-tiers) (July 2023):

> ### Medium SaaS runners on Linux available to all tiers
>
> We have now made our medium [GitLab SaaS runner on Linux](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html) with 4 vCPUs and 16 GB RAM available to all tiers.
>
> Previously users on the Free tier were only able to use our small Linux runner, sometimes causing longer CI/CD execution times.
> We are excited to see our Free users accelerate their pipeline speeds.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/418124).